# Send encrypted id/password from a jsp form to a controller

Tags: ajax, security, authentication, form-submit

I have a jsp with a 'login' link. On click of Login, a div appears on the top of page. I need to submit my id\password  through an ajax call to a spring controller (java) which will then validate it.

Can this Form Submit be secured or encrypted in some way ? (I can use only javascript for this)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003325/send-password-safely-using-an-ajax-request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269598/ajax-login-password-encryption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To submit the form safely you just have to set the form submit method as 'POST'. Otherwise you can create a new form in javascript function like:

```
function toPost(getString) 
{
     // create form element

        var newForm = document.createElement("form"); 
        newForm.action = <url to post data>;
        newForm.method = 'POST'; 

    // Hidden field to be send   
        var newH = document.createElement("input");

   // set any desired name here

        newH.name = <name to be set>; 
        newH.type = 'hidden'; 
        newH.value = <value to post>;
        newForm.appendChild(newH);
        newForm.submit();
}
```

If you want to send more than one fields than add more fields according to your need.

Comment: POST is almost as unsafe as  GET. If you know how to use Firebug, you can see the ID and password loud and clear. I need some way to secure my ajax call since I can't afford SSL.

Comment: Encrypt the username and password and send them in encrypted form than it will be more secured but not secured like in SSL. Otherwise try to find some alternative according to your needs...