# Best way to pass a password via GET or POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, authentication, get

I have made a simple login form, but what is bugging me is that if you view the request (it's ajax), you can see the users password i.e. ?user=Bob&pass=secret

Is this something not to worry about at all or am I doing it wrong? I can't think of a way around this.

Comment: 'if you view the request' - who's 'you' and how exactly they 'view' the request?

Comment: this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003325/send-password-safely-using-an-ajax-request

Answer (score 5):

Always use HTTPS and always opt for POST. The GET method will allow your browser to store the username and password when it stores the URL in its history and can also be sent to third party sites, e.g., google analytics. Also, servers will often log the request data including query string parameters. It's pretty clear why using GET is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using **SSL** then **GET** and **POST** are equivalent. Although POST is more secure as compared to GET when SSL is present.

GET sends the data unencrypted but when you will use SSL then the HTTP data which will be send will be encrypted and hence it will be secure.

You can check out the related thread:- [Send password safely using an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003325/send-password-safely-using-an-ajax-request)

Comment: Furthermore, if a password is sent via `GET`, the length will be constrained to the URL's maximum length.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to view the request, you can view the password whether it is an unencrypted GET or POST request.

To protect your users, the best practice is to serve both the login page itself and POST the data to your server over SSL. That will help prevent nefarious parties from viewing the request and seeing that sensitive information.

If you want to take it a step further you can securely hash the users password in Javascript before even being sent to your server. Here is some more information on that: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76939/why-almost-no-webpages-hash-passwords-in-the-client-before-submitting-and-hashi

Comment: Currently I'm hashing serverside using PBKDF2 with 16000 iterations. Hashing client-side might be slow for some people with poor machines, and would putting it all client-side introduce new security problems regarding the hash?

Comment: @imperium2335:- I would suggest you to use bcrypt for securing password:- http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: @imperium2335:- Also check this related thread for your query:- http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-makes-a-hash-function-good-for-password-hashing

Comment: It changes the security profile, certainly, but I'm not sure if its better or worse. Not transmitting a password at all would be the best, and hashing on the client side (as long as it is done securely) is a step in that direction.

Comment: The farthest you can take this that I'm aware of would be SRP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol)

Comment: @ctcherry Thanks for the link, unfortunately the blog that has the PHP implementation no longer exists. Do you know of an easy to follow implementation?

Comment: I updated the link to a wikipedia page (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) which has an example in Python that you can check out and translate to whatever language you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use post or get over https... Http post and get requests are plain text.