# Not sure how to use PHP function in HTML file that leverages JS variables from that HTML file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an index HTML page that grabs a user's username and password from a form.

I want to base 64 encode this before passing it to a php file that makes a request to a server with the encoded credentials.

I tried doing something like:

```
<script>
// The below function calls the PHP file responsible for retrieving campaign details. 
function getCampaignDetails() {
    var username = $('#username').val(); //This successfully returns the username.
    var password = $('#password').val(); //This successfully returns the password.
    
    var authentication_string = <?php $username = urldecode($_GET['username']); $password = urldecode($_GET['password']); echo base64_encode($username.':'.$password); ?>;
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/testing/get_campaign_details.php",
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        data: {
            "authentication_string": authentication_string
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

But I get an error about an unexpected token < which I'm assuming is a syntax error in the authentication_string value. If I add quotes around this value, the php doesn't execute and I get the whole string as is passed to the php file, rather than the encoded credentials.

Is there a way to use PHP in a basic HTML file that grabs a JavaScript variable value, uses a PHP function to get a new value, and then pass back this new value to the data in an Ajax request from the HTML file that is then subsequently utilized by another PHP file?

Or is there a way to base 64 encode something using an HTML/JavaScript function instead of PHP function?

Best,

Comment: Are you putting plaintext passwords in the querystring?!?!

Comment: I'm trying to base 64 encode them before passing.

Comment: BTW I figured out a method using "btoa". 
var authentication_string = window.btoa(username.concat(":",password));

However... I'd like to give you feedback @John Conde.

I'm not a very experienced developer, but can tell you see something very wrong with my code by the excess punctuation. Rather than condemning me, it would be appreciated if you could explain what I'm doing wrong so I can make my code better in the future.

Are you suggesting I shouldn't pass the username and passwords to variables even though I am base encoding them?

Comment: Please don't put passwords in the url, that is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Is it wrong to put password in the URL if they are encoded with base 64 encoding?

Comment: I can't authenticate via the APIs I'm using unless I pass them a base 64 encoded password.

Comment: @user2946613 the base64 encoding makes no difference, an attacker could just execute `<?php echo base64_decode($the_password_in_get); ?>` and get the plaintext password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotation marks around the php that you're running to get the `authentication_string`.

```
var authentication_string = "<?php $username = urldecode($_GET['username']); $password = urldecode($_GET['password']); echo base64_encode($username.':'.$password); ?>";
```

Javascript is expecting a value that it can assign to the variable `authentication_string` after the = like an int or a string. When it see's < it doesn't know what to do with it so it throws an unexpected token error.

As a sidenote - passing a username and password in the querystring (the url) is not a good idea. Even though they are encoded it's better to keep those kind of things away from prying eyes. There's a post here that might be helpful on how to handle sensitive data like that.  [Best way to pass a password via GET or POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343134/best-way-to-pass-a-password-via-get-or-post)

Comment: Thank you. I checked the post you linked to but don't really understand a better way to pass the username and password. Fortunately I am just running this on a local server and so I think it should be OK for me to continue authenticating like I am. If my tool is made external I will speak with our engineer leads about the best way to authenticate otherwise.